# Spring: Stored procedure output parameters return in wrong order

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using [SimpleJdbcCall](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html) to execute stored procedures as follow:

```
public static List<Object> callSp(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, String storedProcedureName, Object... inParameters) {
    try {
        final SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName(storedProcedureName);
        return newArrayList(jdbcCall.execute(inParameters).values());
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Everything working as a charm, but I faced following problem: stored procedures output parameters returns in wrong order. So, if you don't have information about output - you cannot process it right. As I found out, this is happen because in [JdbcTemplate#extractOutputParameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#extractOutputParameters-java.sql.CallableStatement-java.util.List-) used HashMap to collect output (instead of LinkedHashMap, where entries order the same as insert order).

I know that I can explicitly define output, but I don't have such information, this method should works with any of the passed stored procedure. Also, I know that there is possibility to use [StoredProcedure](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html), but there will be the same problem as it uses the same JdbcTemplate method.

Currently, as a temporary solution, I retrieve information about output (name and ordinal position), from DB metadata and map returned values regarding this.

Did anyone face this problem and what was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of spring-jdbc you're using? If [>=4.2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12801) then have your tried named parameters?

Output parameters can be registered like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.call(new CallableStatementCreator() {
@Override
    CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement stmnt = con.createCall("{foo(?, ?, ?)}");

        stmnt.registerOutParameter("id", Types.INTEGER);
        stmnt.setString("name", "somevalue");
        stmnt.setDate("description", "anothervalue");

        return stmnt;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Im using 4.2.1. As i know, named parameters, used only for input parameters. Am i wrong?

Comment: I've applied codesample that we're using for output parameters.

Comment: In your solution, i still need to know names of output parameters